# Codemirror creating another editor textarea above the initial editor textarea on button click

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

**HTML Codemirror Text Area**

```
<textarea name = "mytarget" id = "mytarget" class="codemirror-textarea2"> 
</textarea>
```

**HTML Button to update Codemirror Text Area**

```
<p><input type="button" name="buttonsubmit" class="buttoncls" value="Submit"></p>
```

**SCRIPT Create Codemirror Textarea on window ready**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var code = $(".codemirror-textarea2")[0];
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(code, {
        lineNumbers : true,
        mode: "javascript",
        theme: "default"
        });
    });
```

**SCRIPT Create click button event**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.buttoncls', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( window ).click(send_hello);
    });
});
```

**SCRIPT Update Codemirror editor**
The data.result comes in fine but setValue is creating another codemirror editor above the one that was already created from the initial load.  I just want to update the editor with the data.result.

```
function receive_hello(data){
    CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(".codemirror-textarea2")[0], {
        lineNumbers: true
    }).setValue(data.result);
  };
```

**I also cannot get the value in the textarea.**

```
CodeMirror.fromTextArea($(".codemirror-textarea2")[0]).getDoc().getValue();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: did you resolve this?